# Why is the IF (A || B) condition evaluated TRUE when one of its condition is FALSE?

Tags: if-statement, binary-search-tree

```
    private void case1(Tree t, Tree root) {  
    //System.out.println(root.left != t);
    if (root.left != t || root.right != t)
        case1(t, (root.value > t.value) ? root.left : root.right);
    else {
        if (root.left == t)
            root.left = null;
        else
            root.right = null;
    }
```

Why is the first IF condition evaluated TRUE even when root.left is actually equal to 't'? I have verified with print to console and the first condition does come out to be false. So the IF condition should be false, but the statement is still evaluated. The entire code is pretty big; I can provide more snippets if necessary.

Comment: Is this language-specific?

Comment: `F or T` is true ... if the first term comes up false, it must evaluate the second term to determine the outcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use && as || is for (OR) operator as if even one statement is true it will return true and in case of (AND) the both statements in if must be true only then it will return true.